# Android Switch Drag and Drop

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to understand how a switch works.
I have a radiobutton that should be checked if the switch is on and vice versa.
However the switch's onClick method only works when you click on the switch. If I drag the switch from off to on it doesn't work at all. How do I solve this? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [`OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html#ClickListener) with that instead of `onClick`.

Comment: How do I do that? It doesn't work for me when I write this: Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
    s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener);

Comment: Did you check the link? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html#ClickListener

Comment: That's weird, can you edit the question and include the code you are using for that switch?